# FlutterError No ScaffoldMessenger widget found

Tags: flutter

FlutterError (No ScaffoldMessenger widget found.
MyApp widgets require a ScaffoldMessenger widget ancestor.
The specific widget that could not find a ScaffoldMessenger ancestor was:
MyApp
The ancestors of this widget were:
_InheritedProviderScope<UserProvider?>
ChangeNotifierProvider
_NestedHook
MultiProvider
[root]
Typically, the ScaffoldMessenger widget is introduced by the MaterialApp at the top of your application widget tree.)

**Error this section**

```
void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(text),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) {
  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
    SnackBar(
      content: Text(text),
    ),
  );
}

Future<List<File>> pickImages() async {
  List<File> images = [];
  try {
    var files = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
      type: FileType.image,
      allowMultiple: true,
    );
    if (files != null && files.files.isNotEmpty) {
      for (int i = 0; i < files.files.length; i++) {
        images.add(File(files.files[i].path!));
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    debugPrint(e.toString());
  }
  return images;
}
```

**How should I fix it? I fix the follow video.**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lytQi-slT5Y

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: share code from which part showSnackBar() you calling in your code.

Comment: please include a complete example, as others will be able to help you more accurately

Comment: In the Widget you call showSnackBar, the ScaffoldContext is not included, you can try to pass in the context in the parent component

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73437095/unhandled-exception-no-scaffoldmessenger-widget-found) I tried doing it from the same link. and stuck with the same problem, just found it but still don't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you've shared still doesn't show where you are calling the snackBar() but according to what is there, it seems you're trying to call it in a "business logic file" without properly passing the BuildContext. It is required by the method, yes, but your not passing the context from the main app. Ensure to pass a context from the widget tree